# For loop python print differently

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is code:

```
start = 1
end = 3
a = "one"
b = "two"
for x in range(start, end + 1):
    print a
    print b
    print b
    print b
```

output:

```
one
two
two
two
one
two
two
two
one
two
two
two
```

Desired output:

```
one
two
two
two
two
one
one
one
one
two
two
two
```

Some one please help me to get desired output

fist time print a, followed by three times b, second time print b, followed by three times a, third time print a, followed by three times b and so on

Answer (score 4):

So, basically you want a and b to switch places in subsequent iterations. Just add this:

```
a, b = b, a
```

at the end of your loop…

Comment: Correct answer, another possible suggestion is to change the repeated `print b` with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is creating a loop that runs the code that prints a, followed by b three times. This code is then just repeated as many times as the loop runs. What you can do is use a boolean that changes between true and false after each loop.

```
start = 1
end = 3
a = "one"
b = "two"
Start_A = True
for x in range(start, end + 1):
if Start_A == True:
    print a
    print b
    print b
    print b
    Start_A = False
elif Start_A == False:
    print b
    print a 
    print a
    print a
    Start_A = True
```

Something like this produces the output you want.